# MUI How to update a useState in TabPanel without re-rendering TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been working with React and MUI for only a few months now, and ran into an issue that I can't solve.

**The Intent:**

I have data coming in from a backend, and I want to display it and allow users to edit and send the edited data back to the backend, all without editing the original copy of the data (the backend will verify the user data first). I do this by using the backend data as Default values, and any changes to the inputs populate a new dictionary that is sent to the backend. That way, if the user makes changes but doesn't save them, the original data is retained on the frontend without needing to request it again.

**The Issue:**

Any time an Input's onChange event happens in the TabPanel's children components (such as a TextField's onChange event), the TabPanel re-renders, which reloads the default value back into the TextField, and de-selects the TextField. This makes the components functionally unuseable.

Example Code:

EditDialog.jsx:

```
...MUI Component Imports
import EditInfo from './EditInfo.jsx'
import EditNotifications from './EditNotifications.jsx'


// Main Function start
export default function EventEditDialog(props){

  const { socket, open, onClose, id, eventData } = props;

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState()
  const [newValues, setNewValues] = useState({})

  // Editable Data Fields
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0)


  {/*
      useEffect Hooks
  */}
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EventEditDialog->eventData', eventData)
  }, [eventData] )


  useEffect(() => {
    setPayload({...newValues, 'modified_by': 'Web User'})
    console.log('EventEditDialog->newValues = ', newValues)
  }, [newValues] )



  {/* 
    MUI Tab setup
      https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/
  */}
  function TabPanel(props) {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', height:'100%', width: '100%'}}
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
        {...other}>
          {value === index && (
            <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 5, width: '100%' }}>
              {children}
            </Box>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };

  function tabProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }

  const handleChangeTab = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue)
  }
  // End Tabs


  {/*
      Edit Dialog Apply and Close Functions
  */}
  const handleEditEvent = (value) => {

    onClose(value);

    if (Object.keys(payload).length > 0) {
      console.log('[ModalEdit] payload: ', payload)
      SendEdit(socket, eventData.event_id, payload)
    }
  }

  const handleCloseEdit = () => {
    onClose()
  }


  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleCloseEdit} open={open} PaperProps={{ style: { minWidth:"60%" }}} >
      <DialogTitle>Edit Event</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent style={{maxHeight: "85%"}} >
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={handleChangeTab} aria-label="simple tab example">
            <Tab label="Event Info" {...tabProps(0)} />
            <Tab label="Notifications" {...tabProps(1)} />
          </Tabs>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={0}>
            <EditInfo id={id} eventData={eventData} newValues={newValues} setNewValues={setNewValues}/>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={1}>
            <EditNotifications eventData={eventData}/>
          </TabPanel>
        </Box>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleEditEvent}>Apply</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>


  )
}


EventEditDialog.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  // id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  // eventData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

EditInfo.jsx:

```
...MUI Component Imports

export default function EditInfo(props){
  const { id, eventData, newValues, setNewValues } = props

  {/*
    useEffect Hooks
  */}
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EditInfo->eventData', eventData)
  }, [eventData] )

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EditInfo->newValues= ', newValues)
  }, [newValues] )


  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={1} marginTop={2}>
        <Grid xs={1}>
          <TextField
            id="event-id"
            label="Event"
            value={id}
            sx={{width: '100%'}}
            disabled
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={10}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="event-name"
            label="Name"
            defaultValue={eventData.name}
            sx={{width: '100%'}}
            onChange={e => {
              setNewValues({...newValues, 'name': e.target.value})
              console.log('TextField->newValues', newValues)
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}


EditInfo.propTypes = {
  // onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  // id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  eventData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

The Question:
How can I get data from the child components of a TabPanel without rerendering the TabPanel everytime the data changes?

Thanks!

Comment: This is because you define a component inside a component (`TabPanel` inside `EventEditDialog`). The issue isn't exactly the rerendering, it's that when `EventEditDialog` rerenders it creates a completely new component type (`TabPanel`) which has a different reference to the `TabPanel` from the last render cycle. Because of this new reference React will see it as completely different, it will unmount the old component and mount the new component. TLDR move `TabPanel` definition outside `EventEditDialog` or at the very least memoize it.

Comment: @JacobSmit Thank you! I'm still trying to wrap my head around all the re-renders, and I completely missed that. Moving the definition outside the function worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jacob Smit commented, I just needed to move the definition of TabPanel out of the function.

The new EditDialog.jsx looks like this:

```
...MUI Component Imports
import EditInfo from './EditInfo.jsx'
import EditNotifications from './EditNotifications.jsx'

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', height:'100%', width: '100%'}}
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}>
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 5, width: '100%' }}>
          {children}
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function tabProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}


// Main Function start
export default function EventEditDialog(props){

  const { socket, open, onClose, id, eventData } = props;

  const [payload, setPayload] = useState()
  const [newValues, setNewValues] = useState({})

  // Editable Data Fields
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0)


  {/*
      useEffect Hooks
  */}
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EventEditDialog->eventData', eventData)
  }, [eventData] )


  useEffect(() => {
    setPayload({...newValues, 'modified_by': 'Web User'})
    console.log('EventEditDialog->newValues = ', newValues)
  }, [newValues] )



  const handleChangeTab = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue)
  }


  {/*
      Edit Dialog Apply and Close Functions
  */}
  const handleEditEvent = (value) => {

    onClose(value);

    if (Object.keys(payload).length > 0) {
      console.log('[ModalEdit] payload: ', payload)
      SendEdit(socket, eventData.event_id, payload)
    }
  }

  const handleCloseEdit = () => {
    onClose()
  }


  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleCloseEdit} open={open} PaperProps={{ style: { minWidth:"60%" }}} >
      <DialogTitle>Edit Event</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent style={{maxHeight: "85%"}} >
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={handleChangeTab} aria-label="simple tab example">
            <Tab label="Event Info" {...tabProps(0)} />
            <Tab label="Notifications" {...tabProps(1)} />
          </Tabs>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={0}>
            <EditInfo id={id} eventData={eventData} newValues={newValues} setNewValues={setNewValues}/>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value={tabValue} index={1}>
            <EditNotifications eventData={eventData}/>
          </TabPanel>
        </Box>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleEditEvent}>Apply</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>


  )
}


EventEditDialog.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  // id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  // eventData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```